# Rails: Redirect to user's profile inside comments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comments, associations, acts-as-commentable

I have a pretty simple comment system in my rails app - I would like to allow user to clic on commenters name to access his profile.

But without any success - I am not sure what I am missing.

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>

          <p><a href="<%= user_path(@comment.user_id) %>" style="text-decoration : none"><%= image_tag comment.user.image, class: "img-circle", width: "30x30" if comment.user %><font class="small" color="#28c3ab"> @<%= comment.user.name if comment.user %></font></a> 

<% end %>
```

But I have a no routes match error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

Any ideas what I am missing? I Know it's something easy but I'm out of ideas for now. Where should I add this call in my controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that your problem might be the `@comment`

change:

```
user_path(@comment.user_id)
```

to:

```
user_path(comment.user_id)
```

Comment: This is the same. Internally, the first call is translated into the second.

Comment: @zacchj check this might be the problem

Comment: How could I miss that :( ! Thanks dude

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `@comment.user_id`. It's likely there is no `user_id` assigned to the instance and the value is `nil`.

Comment: Strange, comments are associated to users => 2.1.1 :006 > Comment = Comment.first
  Comment Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments"   ORDER BY "comments"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
(irb):6: warning: already initialized constant Comment
/Users/jeremyzaccherini/Desktop/fundmymac/app/models/comment.rb:1: warning: previous definition of Comment was here
 => #<Comment id: 1, content: "beautiful", commentable_id: 2, commentable_type: "Pin", created_at: "2014-08-18 14:13:31", updated_at: "2014-08-18 14:13:31", user_id: 3>

Comment: As you can see, there is a user_id associated to each comments

Comment: Your code just demonstrates the first Comment has an user_id. Are you sure each Comment record has an user id? Run `Comment.pluck(:user_id)` and check that the returned array contains no `nil` values.

Comment: This is what it returns:                                       2.1.1 :001 > Comment.pluck(:user_id)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT "comments"."user_id" FROM "comments"
 => [3, 13]